# split arguments with regex

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm using the following code to split incoming requests:

```
    /*
     *   Create global $GET from our cool URL's
     */
    preg_match_all('/[\/|\?|\&]([a-zA-Z\_0-9]+)([\/|=]([0-9]+)){0,1}/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $parts, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    if( count($parts[1]) >= 1 && count($parts[3]) >= 1)
        $GET = array_combine($parts[1], $parts[3]);
```

URL's like "/cat/2/post/345/answer/post" is divided into:

```
cat  => 2
post => 345
answer => 
post =>
```

is it possible to change this regex to allow for urls like: /post/345-title-goes-here/ and make it into:

```
post => 345-title-goes-here
```

becasue right now it only works if the argument is strictly 0-9 with no other characters. and even that was a real problem for me. any suggestions? :)

Comment: I've once again revisited this one, since the old one didn't seem to support single digit values. This is what I use now: `#[/?&]([\w.()-]+)([/=](\d[\w.()-]+|\d))?#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a more concise one:

```
#[/?&](\w+)([/=](\d[\w-]+))?#
```

so the `preg_match_all` becomes:

```
preg_match_all('#[/?&](\w+)([/=](\d[\w-]+))?#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $parts, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

**Update according to comment:**

```
#[/?&]([\w.()-]+)([/=](\d[\w.()-]+))?#
```

You can add every character you want within the character class.

Comment: neat short version , but it makes a url like /registrera/123-hejsan/doh/eller  into     [registrera] => 123-hejsan ,    [doh] => eller
instead of [doh] => , [eller] =>  what i mean is that for it to count as value, i want it to start with 0-9.

Comment: Nice! It sure is short and tidy -evident that you know you'r regex well! Would it be totally ruined if I asked you for supporting signs . - _ ( ) anywhere in both key & value? Only real diffrence I want for values is that it should start with a digit, otherwise, the more URL friendly characters that can be supported on both key&value the better.

Comment: @ChristofferBubach: Of course, you can add any character you want. See my edit.

Comment: Hi, this was a while ago and I've been happily using this version on my sites: 
`'#[/?&]([\w-.]+)([/=](\d[\w-.]+))?#'` (not sure anymore how this one differs from your updated one above)
problem is that this code along with every other version suggested here all fails if I get a URL with "/part/part/" which I discovered due to a relocation error. It should present this as two distinct keys, but only the first one is shown in the array. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Seems like my issue here was that PHP arrays can't hold non-unique keys, so `array_combine` would simply ignore one of them.

Comment: Worth mentioning: `if(count(array_unique($parts[1]))<count($parts[1])) { print "duplicate keys"; }` is an excellent way to detect duplicate keys before combining them.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, instead of:

```
'/[\/|\?|\&]([a-zA-Z\_0-9]+)([\/|=]([0-9]+)){0,1}/'
```

try:

```
'/[\/|\?|\&]([a-zA-Z\_0-9]+)([\/|=]([0-9]+[a-zA-Z_-]*)){0,1}/'
```

I just added the extra characters after the 0-9 in an optional (0 or more) set.

Comment: Doesn't this require that all parameters have a value? For example:

/forum/5-general-talk/thread/45-hi-there/post/answer/
would
result in all right until "post => answer" instead of "post =>" _and_ "answer =>" ?

Comment: The regex need to somehow check that the following string consists of 0-9 then a "-" sign and then any other A-Z,a-z,- after that. Otherwise if it starts with a-z consider it a new parameter/variable.

Comment: Damn I spoke too soon, worked great!  Got my hand on this from another buddy, seems to do even more, allows - in key-name for example.   '/[\/|\?|\&]([a-zA-Z\-\_0-9]+)([\/|=]([0-9]+\-[a-zA-Z\(\)\.\-\_0-9]+|[0-9]+)){0,1}/'